# 15.10 can't connect to wired connection

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, ethernet, 15.10

I was previously toying with using 15.04 on my office computer, and it worked fine out of the box. This week I decided to give it another shot with 15.10 (using beta 2, then the past 3 days' daily builds). I understand these are not release versions, but I doubt that in the next 12 hours, developers will be focused on this specific issue versus more release-related matters.

Anyways, when I boot either the installer or live interface, I cannot connect to my network via my wired connection. The wired connection worked find in 15.04, and works fine when I flip back to Windows. I've tried running lshw -c network, followed by ifconfig, and it is detecting the run-of-the-mill Realtek onboard adapter (model, MAC, etc), and actively trying to get an IP. In the GUI, the network-manager indicator also shows that it's trying to get an IP, but it periodically gives up.

If I manually set an IP with ifconfig, I'm still unable to ping any other devices on the network.

Any suggestions?

Edit: NIC is a Realtek RTL8111E on an ASRock B75M-DGS R2.0 board

Comment: Idle curiosity (though maybe an idea)... What are the chances of you having another ethernet card or a USB wireless adapter?

Comment: @Pilot6 Have you seen this? I know you're good at connections

Comment: @KGIII i don't actually, but I was thinking about grabbing a cheap Intel NIC if I have to. would prefer to avoid the hassle though

Comment: what dose this command out put "sudo dhclient eth0 -v"

Comment: @Neil ran it on both eth0 and enp3s0: http://s18.postimg.org/9twzs75tl/20151026_191315.jpg

Comment: Do you have access to the non-beta 15.10 release on DVD or USB? If so - can you check to see (in the live state) if the NIC issue is present? The latest ISO, not daily build, is available via regular channels.

Comment: @KGIII forgot to mention earlier...my USB is now running the final 15.10 build. Same results.

Comment: Are you sure DHCP is working on the ethernet network? That is, can other computers plug in to that plug?

Comment: @nobugs definitely is. If I flip back to Windows, use my phone, laptop, or coworkers Mac, it connects just fine. All on dhcp.

Comment: What is your network interface name?

Comment: @DanialBehzadi enp3s0

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with wlan0, which is being renamed during startup to wlp2s0.  I think that I have resolved it by fiddling with udev so that the device is renamed back to wlan0.

Answer (score 1):

Get ip from DHCP:

```
$ sudo dhclient enp3s0
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help. Connect to internet an alternative way and run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
sudo modprobe -r r8169
sudo modprobe r8168
```

If you can't connect an alternative way, then you will need to download `r8168-dkms` and `dkms` packages separately.

Answer (score 0):

We have similar issue on 2 machines after 15.10 installation (not upgrade). IP address succefully obtained, local network works OK but internet connection fails (ping connamd showed 100% loss when pinging by hostname or IP). [This link](http://ubuntuguide.net/fix-cannot-connect-to-wired-internet-problem-in-ubuntu-or-ubuntu-vmware-guest) does not solve my problem completly (I cannot see any connection in network-manaher GUI) but now I have access to WEB.

my wired adapter - enp2s0

```
vvs@SVIST:~$ ifconfig -a
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:de:80:c6:b8:9b  
          inet addr:169.254.29.91  Bcast:169.254.29.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::96de:80ff:fec6:b89b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:117 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19571 (19.5 KB)  TX bytes:13798 (13.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:244 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:244 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:23330 (23.3 KB)  TX bytes:23330 (23.3 KB)


vvs@SVIST:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         169.254.29.20   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
169.254.29.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0


vvs@SVIST:~$ ping 169.254.29.20
PING 169.254.29.20 (169.254.29.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 169.254.29.20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=0.325 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.29.20: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=0.346 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.29.20: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=0.343 ms
^C
--- 169.254.29.20 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.325/0.338/0.346/0.009 ms
vvs@SVIST:~$ ping 169.254.29.10
PING 169.254.29.10 (169.254.29.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 169.254.29.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.558 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.29.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.162 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.29.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.195 ms
^C
--- 169.254.29.10 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.162/0.305/0.558/0.179 ms
vvs@SVIST:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.209.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6046ms

vvs@SVIST:~$ dig @169.254.29.20 google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-11ubuntu1-Ubuntu <<>> @169.254.29.20 google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16085
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 5

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     154 IN  A   216.58.209.174

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     166990  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
google.com.     166990  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     166990  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     166990  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.google.com.     341077  IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns2.google.com.     341077  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns3.google.com.     341077  IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.     341077  IN  A   216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 30 msec
;; SERVER: 169.254.29.20#53(169.254.29.20)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 26 15:06:13 EET 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 191
```

what I've done:
Edit the file “/etc/network/interfaces” and change it looks like this:

```
#The loopback network interface - this was default string
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primary network interface - I've add this
iface enp2s0 inet static 
address 169.254.29.64
netmask 255.255.255.0 
gateway 169.254.29.20
dns-nameservers 169.254.29.20
auto enp2s0
```